# Managing a session with ASP.NET site from Java (Apache HttpClient)

Tags: java, asp.net, apache, http, httpclient

I want to fetch a web page from a ASP.NET site that is only accessible from within a session. I'm using Apache HttpClient. I first open the main page of the site, then I search for the link to the "goal" page, and then I fire up a GET request for the "goal" page. The problem is that when I get the response for the second GET request, I always get the same (first) page. If I open the site with Firefox or Google Chrome I get the "goal" page.

From the first response from the server I get the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 12 Dec 2010 19:03:56 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
Platform: Mobitel Pla.NET
Node: 4
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 1.1.4322
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=0vpgd055cifko3mnw4nkuimz; path=/
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 7032
```

I inspected the traffic with WireShark and all headers look OK. I send the correct cookie back to the server on the second GET request.

I'm using Apache HttpClient. I have only one instance of DefaultHttpClient and I reuse that for the second request. I have BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY Cookie Policy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my stupid mistake.

The mistake was that I was sending the second GET request to a link, without replacing the ampersand character codes.

Ex:

```
/(0vpgd055cifko3mnw4nkuimz)/Mp.aspx?ni=1482&amp;pi=72&amp;_72_url=925b9749-b7c7-4615-9f1a-9b613c344c82
```

That is wrong, because I send `&amp;` instead of `&`

The RIGHT way to do it is:

```
/(0vpgd055cifko3mnw4nkuimz)/Mp.aspx?ni=1482&pi=72&_72_url=925b9749-b7c7-4615-9f1a-9b613c344c82
```

Answer (score 1):

You need send back this header from the client (send back the cookie you received) in all your further requests:

```
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=0vpgd055cifko3mnw4nkuimz; // and all other cookies
```

That should do the trick